# How do I call a function I wrote from the main class?

Tags: java

I wrote a function `remove(int x)` that removes a copy of x from the collection and returns true if a copy of x was removed.

```
//boolean remove method
public  boolean remove(int value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (values[i] == value) {
                        --size;
                        for (; i < size; ++i) {
                                values[i] = values[i + 1];
                        }
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
}
```

How can I call boolean remove method in main class?

Comment: Can you please provide the whole code, including your `main class` and specify where you want to call this function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean remove(int value) {
    Boolean bool = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] == value) {
            values[i] = -1; 

            if (values[i] == -1)
                bool = true;
        }
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Let -1 signify a removed value, you can change this to any other value.
Let me know if this helps.

UPDATE:
If this method is in the same file as your main simply make the following stetment:

```
remove(YOUR_INT_VALUE);
```

Or if this method is located in a different class create an instance of the class:

```
CLASSNAME something = new CLASSNAME();
```

CLASSNAME Is the file name where the method remove is located (without the added .java)
something is just a reference name for that instance so you can name it anything (e.g. remover, r, noScope))
And then you can call like this:

```
something.remove(YOUR_INT_VALUE);
```

Comment: But how can I call it from main?? Thank you,

Comment: Thank you ver much, it works now – Sara just now   edit

Comment: The part beginning "If this method is in the same file as your main ...." is incorrect, because `main` is static, but this method is not.  So you'll still have to create an object, whether this method is in the same class as `main` or not.

Comment: Thanks David for your comment, I made the method static so I do not need an object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to remove elements from a Collection (not an array):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Snippet {
    // collection example to start with
    private static Collection<Integer> col = 
            new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(1); add(2); add(3); }};

    public static boolean remove(int value) {
        for (Integer element : col) {
            // look for the value in the collection
            if (element == value) {
                // remove if exists
                col.remove(element);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // testing ...
        System.out.println("starting with collection : " + col);
        System.out.println("removing 1 returns " + col.remove(1) + ". collection is now " + col);
        System.out.println("removing 6 returns " + col.remove(1) + ". collection is now " + col);
    }
}
```